# "he looks at the stars" / "he looks at stars"

Tags: articles, definite-article

> We only use **the** with general plural nouns when we are **referring to a specific set** within a general class of people or things. [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/determiners/a-an-and-the)

Why are the following "stars" referring to a specific set?

> - Everyone is in trouble when he looks at **the stars**, and under the stars ... [link](https://books.google.ae/books?id=0W1AkxEVwA8C&pg=PA114&dq=%22He%20looks%20at%20the%20stars%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22He%20looks%20at%20the%20stars%22&f=false)
> - But he will be happy when he looks at **the stars** and hears in his memory ... [link](https://books.google.ae/books?id=UqeNR5qdHSkC&pg=PA167&dq=%22He%20looks%20at%20the%20stars%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22He%20looks%20at%20the%20stars%22&f=false)

and these aren't?

> - He looks at the sky, and at **stars** in particular ... [link](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/es/stories-poems/nace-una-estrella)
> - He looks at **stars** that could swallow up a thousand of our suns ... [link](https://books.google.ae/books?id=1CA-G6wovgkC&pg=PA164&dq=%22He%20looks%20at%20stars%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22He%20looks%20at%20stars%22&f=false)

Another examples:

> - She looks at **the reports** and approves them ... [link](https://books.google.ae/books?id=5BQBDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT44&dq=%22she%20looks%20at%20the%20reports%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22she%20looks%20at%20the%20reports%22&f=false)
> - When I look at **the reports** in Die Kerkbode on the events  ... [link](https://books.google.ae/books?id=hnTvMmD1UsEC&pg=PA193&dq=%22I%20look%20at%20the%20reports%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22I%20look%20at%20the%20reports%22&f=false)

> - Celia Mather looks at **reports** which reveal the appallingly low standard of management practices ... [link](https://books.google.ae/books?id=XtRYAAAAYAAJ&q=%22looks%20at%20reports%22&dq=%22looks%20at%20reports%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y)
> - Instead, he looks at **reports** that are in various stages of preparation or being drafted ...  [link](https://books.google.ae/books?id=lKwTAQAAMAAJ&q=%22he%20looks%20at%20reports%22&dq=%22he%20looks%20at%20reports%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y)

Comment: "Look at **the stars**" can be similar in meaning to "look at **the sky**" - we are not speaking of any group of stars (known or being introduced) but generally about the starry sky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
He looks at the stars
```

Here, the specific set of stars are all of the ones which are visible to him at that time.

```
He looks at stars
```

Here, there is no specific set of stars which he looks at, it implies that he looks at individual stars or small groups of them at random.

```
He looks at stars in particular...
He looks at stars that ...
```

Here he looks at specific stars which have certain characteristics as opposed to all of those that he can see.